# A query where either field can be true

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm creating a query with 4 fields (for example: skill, skill months, industry, industry fields). You can select Skill = A, Skill Months > 4, and Industry = B, Industry Months > 2.

I want to see people who had Skill A for more than 4 months, Industry B for more than 2 months, or even both.

Right now the query will only show people who had both experience in Skill A AND Industry B.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from MyTable
Where (Skill = 'A' and SkillMonths > 4)
Or (Industry = 'B' and IndustryMonths > 2)
```

or somesuch.

Comment: Where would that go? The SQL?

Comment: This is the current SQL code: SELECT EmployeeNewFull.Name, IndustryKey.IndustryName, [Industry non consulting].MonthsNonCon, IndustryKey.IndustryName, [Industry consulting].MonthsCon
FROM IndustryKey INNER JOIN ((EmployeeNewFull INNER JOIN [Industry consulting] ON EmployeeNewFull.[Employee ID] = [Industry consulting].[Employee ID]) INNER JOIN [Industry non consulting] ON EmployeeNewFull.[Employee ID] = [Industry non consulting].[Employee ID]) ON (IndustryKey.IndustryID = [Industry non consulting].IndustryID) AND (IndustryKey.IndustryID = [Industry consulting].IndustryID);

Comment: huh? you might want to change your question a bit